# MySQL convert YEARWEEK to date

Tags: mysql

I've a YEARWEEK() converted value from MySQL

```
201439
```

I want to convert it back to the starting date of that week number, using MySQL, possible?

e.g.

```
SELECT xxx('201439');
```

and return

```
'2014-09-16'
```

Comment: Something like `DATE('2014-01-01') + INTERVAL 39 WEEK`

Comment: I get your updated question.
My solution is you need to create a very simple function in your source code to parse from **String result** you got from queries to the pattern you want.
For example you can use **subString** to cut and fill it to your pattern. :D

Answer (score 32):

You need to be careful that the yearweek is in the expected "mode". (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

The formatting used in the STR_TO_DATE should match. (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

e.g. If using mode 2 (1-53, Week 1 is the first week with a Sunday in it, weeks start on a Sunday)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201439',' Sunday'), '%X%V %W');
```

e.g. If using mode 3 (following ISO-8601), (1-53, Week 1 is the first week with 4 or more days, starting on a Monday), you need to use the lower-case version.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201439',' Monday'), '%x%v %W');
```

So, one would get the following (2014-09-28 is a Sunday):

```
SELECT yearweek('2014-09-28', 2);
201439
SELECT yearweek('2014-09-28', 3);
201439
SELECT yearweek('2014-09-29', 2);
201439
SELECT yearweek('2014-09-29', 3);
201440
```

then

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201439',' Sunday'), '%X%V %W'); -- mode 2
2014-09-28
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201439',' Monday'), '%x%v %W'); -- mode 3 
2014-09-22
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201440',' Monday'), '%x%v %W'); -- mode 3
2014-09-29
```

Comment: this is helpful but also confusing and an example including mode 0 (the default mode) would be helpful.

Comment: And it doesn't always give the correct result. My MySQL has default_week_format=3 so WEEK() gives the correct result as does YEARWEEK() with mode 3. But for week 202053 AND 202101 STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(202053,' Monday'), '%X%V %W') returns the same result: 2021-01-04.Try this for fun: SELECT @@default_week_format AS mode, YEAR('2021-01-04')*100+WEEK('2021-01-04') AS `WEEK('2021-01-04')`, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(202053,' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS `STR_TO_DATE('202053')`, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(202101,' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS `STR_TO_DATE('202101')`, YEARWEEK('2021-01-04', 3).

Answer (score 14):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE` function with [format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you need

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/2017

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW()),' Monday'), '%X%V %W');

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201439',' Monday'), '%X%V %W');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(LEFT('201439', 4), '-01-01')) + INTERVAL RIGHT('201439', 2)-1 WEEK
```

This won't get the beginning of the week, it will get the same day of the week as January 1 of that year.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this code likes example:

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
```

Hope you like it! ^^

Comment: What language is that?