# How to group by week with Django ORM

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-orm

I am using the following SQL code to check previous sunday:

> DATE_ADD(tbl.date, INTERVAL (- 1) * DAYOFWEEK(tbl.date) + 1 DAY) AS
>   week

Could you tell me whether I can use the same thanks to django models ?

I have completely no idea how to do this.

In another words I want to group by sunday in my query

My model:

```
class tbl_data( models.Model ):

    date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date")
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Identifier")
    value = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Value")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str( self.date ) + '-' + str( self.identifier )
```

data is uploading everyday, I want to group it by week ( Sunday is my first day )

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, you can do that with django.

Comment: that's great :-) can you explain how I can do that ?

Comment: Have you made a model yet?  Start there.  Then show us that code and ask the question in that context.

Comment: yes, I've made my model, just edited the main post. Thanks

Comment: The official Django documentation has a page about [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: I know that page, but do not see there any information about grouping by sunday or another day of the week

Comment: A Django `DateField` is represented in Python by a `datetime.date` instance So in Python code you can use `date.weekday()` or `date.isoweekday()` on it. Then use the aggregation as @cezar suggested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Query Group By Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851053/django-query-group-by-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't state which database system you're using, but I'll assume it is MySQL (or MariaDB) and provide an example based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851053/django-query-group-by-month).

We'll make use of the MySQL function [`YEARWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek). For that purpose will create a python class inheriting from `Func`:

```
from django.db.models import Func, IntegerField

class YearWeek(Func):
    function = 'YEARWEEK'
    template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s)'
    output_field = IntegerField()
```

Now we can make a query like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from yourapp.models import tbl_data
from yourapp.filewhityearweek import YearWeek

result = tbl_data.objects.annotate(  
    yearweek=YearWeek('date')
).values('yearweek').annotate(
    count=Count('date')
).order_by('yearweek')
```

This will return something like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'yearweek': 201801, 'count': 5}, {'yearweek': 201802, 'count': 3}, {'yearweek': 201803, 'count': 2}]>
```

Depending on your data the result will certainly vary.

The SQL query produced by Django ORM will look like this:

```
SELECT
    YEARWEEK('tbl_data'.'date') AS 'yearweek',
    COUNT('tbl_data'.'date') AS 'count'
FROM 'tbl_data'
    GROUP BY YEARWEEK('tbl_data'.'date')
    ORDER BY 'yearweek' ASC
```

This should help you to group your entries by calender week. Using `YEARWEEK` should give you better overview than functions like `WEEK` as it is returning the year and the calender week.

Comment: hey , it helps a lot , thanks a lot! one quesion, in the case of this date: 2017-12-31 it returns 201753. Is there a possibility to convert the formula to such code ? :

Comment: YEARWEEK(ADDDATE(my_date,5-DAYOFWEEK(my_date)),3)

Comment: or
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(my_date,5-DAYOFWEEK(my_date)),'%x-%v')

Comment: it would be really thankful. and yes, i am using mysql

Comment: The function `YEARWEEK` accepts an optional second argument called `mode`. Please check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week). You can play with it and adjust many things like Sunday or Monday being the starting day of the week and beyond.

Comment: If you want to get the starting date for the week, then please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364141/mysql-convert-yearweek-to-date). You could do something like this: `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT("the week you've got", " Sunday"), "%X%V %W")`. Unfortunately I couldn't manage to write a python class for that.